# Can't update application in Ubuntu Software without first removing it?

Tags: software-center, 20.10, 21.04

If I download a .deb file (e.g. for discord) when I already have the application installed, when clicking it, it opens Ubuntu Software Centre on the application, but I only have the option to remove.

So everytime I want to update an application like that, I need to

1. Click the .deb file
2. Remove the application
3. Close the Software Centre
4. Click the .deb file
5. Install the application

On another PC running the same version of Ubuntu I don't have this issue so feel like it must be a setting somewhere?

For example in the screenshot below, I have Deiscord 0.0.14 installed, so I have downloaded the 0.0.15 deb file (as the application suggests) and opened it.

[image: Software centre with remove option only]